# Laravel: How to load changes from pivot table using laravel-activitylog

Tags: php, laravel

I use  [laravel-activitylog](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/advanced-usage/logging-model-events) to log the changes of the models. And
I have a one-to-many relationship model: an order have an infinite number of details, and the definition is like following:

Order.php:

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    use \App\Models\Concerns\Auditable;

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Detail::class);
    }
}
```

Detail.php:

```php
class Detail extends Pivot
{
    use \App\Models\Concerns\Auditable;

    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $touches = ['order'];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

And I use the following code to update the `Order` and `Detail`:

```php
$order = $this->updateOrder($order, $input);

foreach ($input['details'] as $detail) {
    $pivot = $order->details()->where('id', $detail['id'])->first();
    $pivot->quantity = $detail['quantity'];
    $order->details()->save($pivot);
}
```

When changes are only on `Detail` ( `Order` is no need to update ), `laravel-activitylog` will only record the changes of `Detail` in database.

And how do I show all the changes of `order` including the details ?

Laravel version: 8.51.0

laravel-activitylog version: 4.0.0